# MySQL - Can't connect to local MYSQL server...ERROR 2002?

Tags: mysql, macos

Hi I've looked all over the internet to find an answer to this problem but nothing seems to work. I get the below problem when I try to log in to mysql on terminal in OSX El Capitan.

The server is running.

[image]

What should I do, I've spent 5 hours trying to figure this out before posting this. I cannot find the my.cnf file in /etc and I'm not sure what to do with it. Someone please help.

Edit:

I've downloaded and installed(just double clicking - no terminal) this: 
[image]

When everything is installed and i go into /usr/local/mysql/bin/ and try mysql -u root -p I get the following error:
[image]

This is my my.cnf file in /etc:
[image]

When I do sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe I get this:

[image]

df -h returns this, could it be something to do with space? 
[image]

Comment: Looks to me like you have installed the MySQL Client instead of MySQL Server. Can you check and report back?

Comment: Looks like it. Did you do yum install mysql?

Comment: I went on the mysql website and downloaded MySQL Community Server and installed it the typical way by double clicking. Didn't use the terminal to install it. Any idea how to fix it. I don't mind removing MySQL and starting again because I don't have anything saved. Check post to see which one I've downloaded. Thanks gentlemen.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel more comfortable installing it through the GUI here is an instruction guide on how to do that.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-pkg.html

Make sure you install the MySQLStartupItem.pkg and MySQL.prefPane. After you have done that you can verify your installation by opening up Terminal and running:

```
cd /usr/local
```

hitting enter then typing:

```
ls
```

hit enter again and verify the existence of two directories, one will just be MySQL and the other will be MySQL-(version number you installed).

At this stage I would restart your computer and then on restart the mysql server will start up.

Once it's restarted fire up terminal window again and type this:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

**EDIT**

Open your /etc/my.cnf file and edit these two configurations.

```
[mysqld]
socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock

[client]
socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I followed them instruction and I still get the same error. I don't mind using the terminal to install MySQL if it helps.

Comment: I did all that Steve but the error persists. It won't even let me type the password to enter the mysql database, it just shows the error.

Comment: Updated my post steve with a screenshot of the error

Comment: try restarting your server with this `sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM restart`

Comment: After you reinstalled MySQL are you now able to find your config files?  `/etc/my.cnf`  `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`   `/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: Please check updated post for my.cnf file and its contents in /etc

Comment: When I go do the following: cd then cd /var/lib/mysql there is no mysql.sock file there

Comment: is it here /var/mysql/mysql.sock?

Comment: Yes it's there. Is it supposed to be there? What's supposed to be in that file? When I do nano mysql.sock there is nothing in it.

Comment: Looks like its spawning in the wrong place, edit your /etc/my.cnf file to this path. I will update my answer so its clear what you need to do.

Comment: I've done that and restarted my computer but I still get the error. What I do is: cd  /usr/local/mysql/bin and type mysql -u root - p and enter the password and get that error. Is there anything supposed to be in the mysql.sock file because in my one there's nothing in it.

Comment: No it shouldn't contain anything, try to run this from your terminal to restart your mysqld   `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe`

Comment: Check in directory /usr/local/var/mysql for a file which is named (your-computer-name).local.err if it is owned my _mysql (or similar) delete it and then try start the server again with `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe`

Comment: It was there, owned by _mysql, so I deleted it and restarted as you mentioned. Error still persists. Could it be something to do with free space? When I do df -h I get *check post*

Comment: I doubt it, its more likely to be a privileges issue. I am running out of ideas to be honest you could always try changing ownership like this `sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql`

Comment: Is there a way that I can completely delete everything to do with MySQL and start again? What steps should I follow?

Comment: This is a good process to follow. http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: After a million other attempts, yours worked. Thank you!